# Unable to update openjdk7 and 6 with apt-get

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, lts, openjdk

System: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, Server

I can't update openjdk7 and 6 with apt-get. It always ends with this failers:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main openjdk-6-jre-headl
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main openjdk-6-jdk amd6
  Connection failed
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main openjdk-6-jdk amd64 6b32-1.13.4-4ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Fetched 195 MB in 20min 31s (158 kB/s)
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jdk_7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jre-headless_6b32-1.13.4-4ubuntu0.12.04.2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jdk_6b32-1.13.4-4ubuntu0.12.04.2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Internet-Connection is working, other packets installations working fine.

My /etc/apt/sources.lists, which are not been touched since installation:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130214)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130214)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130214)]/ precise main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130214)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130214)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130214)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your sources.list it seems. To do this run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then continue with your standard installation.

Comment: Thx, but I doit allready, still Connection failed. I tried apt-get clean and update, still Connection failed.

Comment: did you try 'sudo apt-get --fix-mising' like the output suggested?

Comment: Yes of course, i tried "sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing", unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: Try pinging the IPs that aren't connecting (mainly: 91.189.91.13 and 91.189.91.15) Do the servers respond?

Comment: Yes the servers are reachable.
Every package is now updated, only the following java-packages are still old:
`icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-7-jre-jamvm openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless`